# Setting up and solving a recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, sorting

Assume we have two lists, $A$ and $B$; both are sorted lists each with $n$ elements (assume $n$ is a power of 2).

We want to recursively merge the odd-indexed elements from each list: merge $a_1, a_3,...,a_{n-1}$ with $b_1, b_3,...,b_{n-1}$; this will form the list $c_1, c_2,...c_n$. Then do the same for the even-indexed elements: merge $a_2, a_4,...,a_n$ with $b_2, b_4,...,b_n$ to form $d_1, d_2,...,d_n$.

Then consider the shuffled list $c_1, d_1, c_2, d_2,...,c_n, d_n$ and do the following:

$$
\texttt{for } i:= 1\texttt{ to } n-1 \texttt{ do}\\
\hspace{4ex} \texttt{if } (d_i > c_{i+1}) \texttt{ then }\\
\hspace{8ex} \texttt{interchange them}\\
$$

How would I set up and solve a recurrence for the running time *and* the merge sort?

Comment: I expect the recurrence relation for the running time depends on the merge sort algorithm.